Issue with Office Add-in Task Pane Project Using React Framework
I created an Office Add-in Task Pane project using the React framework with the following configuration:
Project Type: Office Add-in Task Pane project using React framework
Script Type: JavaScript
Add-in
Name: outlookapps
Supported Office Client Application: Outlook
Manifest Type: Add-in only manifest
After adding the manifest.xml file to Outlook, the add-in appears in the custom Addins section. However, it does not show up in the App section for usage.
I am unable to see the add-in in the App section where I can use it. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong or how to resolve this issue? Screenshot 1Manually added manifest file
Screenshot 2Add-in not showing in the App section
When I set the project type to "Office Add-in Task Pane project using React framework," the add-in does not appear in the App section for usage. However, if I change the project type to "Office Add-in Task Pane project" (without React), the add-in works as expected.
What might be causing the issue when using the React framework?
How can I properly use the React framework in my Office Add-in Task Pane project?

when i run command npm start it runs a webpack
https://localhost:3000/ the provided link provide cannot/Get
https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html but on this link i'm able to see the content

I just had the same issue. I couldnt figure out any reason neither.
